# Let $F$ be an isometry and $\varphi$ a parametrization at $p\in S_1$, then $\hat{\varphi}=F\circ\varphi$ is a parametrization at $F(p)$

Tags: differential-geometry

Prove the following: Let $F:S_1\to S_2$ be an isometry and $\varphi:U\to S_1$ a parametrization at $p\in S_1$, then $\hat{\varphi}=F\circ\varphi$ is a parametrization at $F(p)$ and $E=\hat{E}$, $F=\hat{F}$ and $G=\hat{G}$, where $E,F,G$ are the coeff. of the first form.

My approach:  Let $F:S_1\to S_2$ an isometry, in particular is a diffeo. and $\varphi:U\to S_1$ a parametrization at $p\in S_1$, so $\hat{\varphi}=F\circ\varphi$ is a diffeom. Then, for all $w_1,w_2\in T_p(S_1)$ let $$E_{\varphi}=\langle\varphi_u,\varphi_u\rangle$$
$$F_{\varphi}=\langle\varphi_u,\varphi_v\rangle$$
$$G_{\varphi}=\langle\varphi_v,\varphi_v\rangle$$

And, by isometry, we have $$\hat{E_\hat{\varphi}}=\langle dF_p(w_1), dF_p(w_2)\rangle_{F(p)}=\langle w_1, w_2\rangle_{p}$$

Thanks.